# how to write parts of a document in 2 columns?

Tags: floats

I would like to write parts of a document in 2 columns. In particular, I would like the text and the image to be side by side.

[image]

This is the code:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}[12pt] 

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}                      

\usepackage{xcolor}    

\linespread{1.5}    

\frenchspacing 

\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig}

\usepackage{multicol}    

  \usepackage[a4paper,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.0cm,left=1.0cm,right=1.0cm]{geometry}     

   \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}    

 \newcommand{\cuthere}{%
 \noindent
 \raisebox{-2.8pt}[0pt][0.75\baselineskip]{\small\ding{34}}
 \unskip{\tiny\dotfill}
 }     

 \newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
   \par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
   \fbox{%
     \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
       \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
       #2
     }%
   }%
   \par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
 }

\begin{document}    

\begin{center}
\textbf{title}
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}   

\item   bla bla bla.

\begin{figure}[!h]
 \centering
 \captionsetup{font={small,it}, labelfont=bf}
 %{\includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{img1.pdf}}
 {\includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image}
 \end{figure}    

\begin{itemize}

\item $ a1: \, \left( \dots \dots \textbf{;} \dots \dots \right)$
\item $ a2: \, \left( \dots \dots \textbf{;} \dots \dots \right)$
\item $ a3: \, \left( \dots \dots \textbf{;} \dots \dots \right)$
\item $ a4: \, \left( \dots \dots \textbf{;} \dots \dots \right)$
\item $ a5: \, \left( \dots \dots \textbf{;} \dots \dots \right)$.    

\end{itemize}    

\item   bla bla bla :     

\end{enumerate}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: please mark up code sections, also use `example-image` not  `img1.pdf` as the latter just gives a file not found error for anyone trying the example

Comment: This looks like a job for wrapfig or  paracol.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
%% why de_DE if you have [itlian]?
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE

%% final option should be a date \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}[12pt] 
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}[12pt] 

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}                      

\usepackage{xcolor}


\linespread{1.5}                

\frenchspacing 

\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

% don't use epsfig unless the document was written in the 1980's \usepackage{floatflt,epsfig}
\usepackage{floatflt}

\usepackage{multicol}

  \usepackage[a4paper,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.0cm,left=1.0cm,right=1.0cm]{geometry}


   \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}


 \newcommand{\cuthere}{%
 \noindent
 \raisebox{-2.8pt}[0pt][0.75\baselineskip]{\small\ding{34}}
 \unskip{\tiny\dotfill}
 }



 \newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
   \par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
   \fbox{%
     \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
       \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
       #2
     }%
   }%
   \par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
 }



\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\textbf{title}
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}


\item   bla bla bla.

% if this is supposed to be in teh list, it should not float
% so should not be a figure  \begin{figure}[!h]
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
 \centering
% \captionsetup{font={small,it}, labelfont=bf}
 \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}
 \end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}

\item $ a1: \, \left( \dots \dots \textbf{;} \dots \dots \right)$
\item $ a2: \, \left( \dots \dots \textbf{;} \dots \dots \right)$
\item $ a3: \, \left( \dots \dots \textbf{;} \dots \dots \right)$
\item $ a4: \, \left( \dots \dots \textbf{;} \dots \dots \right)$
\item $ a5: \, \left( \dots \dots \textbf{;} \dots \dots \right)$.

\end{itemize}

\end{minipage}


\item   bla bla bla : 


\end{enumerate}




\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with `tabularx` and `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, italian]{article}[12pt]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1.0cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float, tabularx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\linespread{1.5}

\frenchspacing

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}()

   \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}

 \newcommand{\cuthere}{%
 \noindent
 \raisebox{-2.8pt}[0pt][0.75\baselineskip]{\small\ding{34}}
 \unskip{\tiny\dotfill}
 }

 \newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
   \par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
   \fbox{%
     \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
       \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
       #2
     }%
   }%
   \par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
 }

 \onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{title}
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}[wide]

\item bla bla bla.\bigskip

\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\centering} X >{\arraybackslash}X@{}}
 \captionsetup{font={small,it}, labelfont=bf}
\raisebox{-0.8\height}{\includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{ladormeuse}}
 \captionof{figure}{
 Sleeping\\Toyen (1937)}
 &\leavevmode
\begin{itemize}[wide = 0pt, leftmargin = *, topsep = 0pt, before = \vspace{-\baselineskip}]
\item $ a1: \, \left( \dots \dots \textbf{;} \dots \dots \right)$
\item $ a2: \, \left( \dots \dots \textbf{;} \dots \dots \right)$
\item $ a3: \, \left( \dots \dots \textbf{;} \dots \dots \right)$
\item $ a4: \, \left( \dots \dots \textbf{;} \dots \dots \right)$
\item $ a5: \, \left( \dots \dots \textbf{;} \dots \dots \right)$.
\end{itemize}
\end{tabularx}

\item bla bla bla :

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! B.t.w., I replaced `\linespread{1.5}` with `\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing`, because it takes into account footnotes and a few other things. Also, note `epsfig` is obsolete and should be replaced with `graphicx`.